# Python Flask Angular application state not refreshing

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am working on flask + Angular + MongoDb application. I am using state provider in angular. states are loading perfectly fine from application. but when i refresh the page it is throwing 404 error.

1. App.py: (Flask)

> ```
>    application = Flask(__name__)
>     @application.route('/')
>     def showMachineList():
>         print ("Inside the show machine list function")
>         return application.make_response(open('templates/index.html').read())
> ```

2. App.js ( Angular)

> ```
> angular.module('testapp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource',
>         'ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap','ngMaterial','ngCookies'
>     ])
>     .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider,$interpolateProvider) {
>         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
>         //$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//').endSymbol('//');
>         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
>     });
> ```

3. State

> ```
> angular.module('testapp')
>   .config(function ($stateProvider) {
>     console.log("inside create outage request")
>     $stateProvider
>       .state('cor', {
>         url: '/cor',
>         template: '<cor></cor>'
>         //templateUrl: '/static/client/app/acn/acn.html'
>       });
>   });
> ```

I have added the `<base href="/">` in index.html as well.
when i refresh the page with `"http://localhost:5000/cor"` its throwing 404.
Can you let me know what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly common problem with Single Page Applications. Looks like your Angular app can handle the `cor` state properly on the client-side, but your web server has no way to know that the `/cor` path should be routed to the same Angular application on the initial load.

Try adding a second route to your endpoint:

```
@application.route('/')
@application.route('/cor')
def showMachineList():
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could use a [catch-all route](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/) to handle any path suffix.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page the browser send the URL "http://localhost:5000/cor" to the server. As I can see in your code, there's no `/cor` route defined, only `/`. I think you have to define one.

```
@application.route('/cor')
def showMachineList():
    with open('templates/index.html') as fd:
        content = fd.read()
    return application.make_response(content)
```

The problem may be in your template: the one where you define the link to `cor`. You should have something like this:

```
<a href="#cor">link to cor</a>
```

I make the assumption that you have written this instead:

```
<a href="/cor">link to cor</a>
```

Comment: But i have defined in the state and i think it should have to load from the Angular state as well.

Comment: You may have a bug in your HTML template.